# How do I safely move / swap files in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsfilemanager

In a cocoa app of mine, there is a method that does some operations on a sqlite database's schema that could be destructive, so first we make a rollback copy of the database, and if there's an error, we call the following method to replace the db file with the rollback file. Note that I definitely want the db file replaced with the rollback!

```
- (BOOL)restoreDatabaseFromFileAtPath:(NSString *)backupPath error:(NSError **)error {
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // get the db paths
    NSString *databasePath = [sharedManager pathToDatabase];

    // insist that the two files be present
    NSAssert1([fm fileExistsAtPath:databasePath], @"no db file at %@", databasePath);
    NSAssert1([fm fileExistsAtPath:backupPath], @"no backup db file at %@", backupPath);

    // remove the original to make way for the backup
    NSLog(@"removing the file at the primary database path...");
    if ([fm removeItemAtPath:databasePath error:error]) {
        // now move the backup to the original location
        NSLog(@"moving the backup file into the primary database path...");
        if ([fm moveItemAtPath:backupPath toPath:databasePath error:error]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    [self presentError:error]; // at this point we're in real trouble
    return NO;
}
```

The code shown does work, but it's potentially very destructive and not exactly atomic. What I would really like to do is something that I imagine exists, but I can't find a way to do it in the API for NSFileManager, something like:

```
Bool success = [fm moveFileAtPath:backupPath toPath:databasePath overwriteDestination:YESPLZ error:&error];
```

The method that comes closest to this barfs when it discovers there's already a file at the destination path.

*Small update based on responses so far:*

There's got to be some standard way this has traditionally been done by Cocoa devs, to atomically replace a file. The various 'move' methods of NSFileManager don't provide a facility for this out of the box. Also, looking to support 10.5 and up in this lib as well as iPhone OS 3+.

Comment: Why not use real SQLite transactions in the database?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with operating on the database necessarily, it could be any file.

For the record, I do use transactions, I have this rollback for a particular operation where a database encrypted with one key and cipher is then re-keyed, a potentially destructive operation, especially if interrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C-level [FSMoveObjectSync](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSMoveObjectSync)/[FSMoveObjectAsync](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSMoveObjectAsync) functions might help. These functions take a set of options, which can include a [flag to overwrite the destination](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Operation_Options), `kFSFileOperationOverwrite`, among other things.

Comment: Ah, now that is interesting, thanks! It's a bit odd to have to drop down to C methods, I feel like there's gotta be a way in Cocoa. But this would do it, for sure.

Comment: Those methods are deprecated as of 10.8

Answer (score 9):

How about `NSFileManager`'s  `replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:`?

[See documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:)

Comment: Note: "Available in Mac OS X v10.6 and later."

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but I'm not convinced this method is appropriate, as it's designed to preserve the meta data of the item being replaced. also, the options parameter doesn't accept any flags indicating that it should over-write the destination, rather than bail because an item already exists at that path/url.

Also, being available only on 10.6 is not so great, my lib needs to support 10.5 and iPhone OS 3+. 

There's gotta be a standard way Cocoa devs have done this for many years ;-)

Comment: @Dewayne good catch, I missed that.

@Billy If you already know that there was an error and you want to roll back, can't you simply delete the destination file and replace it with your rollback?

Comment: @ctshryock Totally! But if this were some other circumstance where I know I want to replace an existing file, I'd be up against the same issue. Perhaps the real answer is elbow grease: move the destination to temp, move the new file in place, remove the old file from temp.

Answer (score 1):

I’d suggest the `FSExchangeObjects`, `PBExchangeObjectsSync` or `PBExchangeObjectsAsync` functions, since they actually swap the contents of two files atomically.

From the [development library](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSExchangeObjects):

> The function allows programs to
> implement a “safe save” operation by
> creating and writing a complete new
> file and swapping the contents.
>
> After the exchange, the access path
> will refer to the opposite file’s data
> (that is, to the same data it
> originally referred, which is now part
> of the other file).
>
> Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.